# grep : multiline + positive lookahead

Tags: regex, grep

I have following lines :

```
[37125.641615] CPU3 is up
[37125.643067] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[37125.683813] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[37125.684233] pci 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[37125.714885] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[37125.714931] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[37125.714935] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[37125.715046] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[37125.715389] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
[37125.716515] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
```

Below is what I'm trying to match (I want to have a match starting with ACPI and delimited with first usb occurence, usb occurence must not be in match)

```
ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[37125.683813] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[37125.684233] pci 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[37125.714885] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[37125.714931]
```

I tried following command :

```
grep -izoP  'ACPI.*(?=usb)' ~/tmp/dmesg_grep_test
```

=> no match, why?

Then I tried this command using multiline grep and positive lookahead:

```
grep -izoP  '(?s)ACPI.*(?=usb)' ~/tmp/dmesg_grep_test 
ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[37125.683813] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[37125.684233] pci 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[37125.714885] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[37125.714931] usb usb2: root hub lost power or was reset
[37125.714935] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
[37125.715046] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[37125.715389] usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
[37125.716515] usb
```

Result is better... but it ends matching to last 'usb' occurence. What I want it match to stop to 'first' occurence of 'usb'.
What is the correct grep command?

PS : I'm asking this question with a simple example using grep tool. Indeed I'm trying to find similar patterns (multiline + positive lookahead) in some pdf files using pdfgrep. That's the answer needs to use grep tool.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `gnu grep` regex with `(?s)` or single-line mode:

```sh
grep -izoP '(?s)\bACPI:.*?(?=\susb\b)' file

ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[37125.683813] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[37125.684233] pci 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[37125.714885] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[37125.714931]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a94vke/2)

**RegEx Explained:**

- `(?s)`: Enable single line mode:
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `ACPI:` Match `ACPI:`
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters including line break (non-greedy)
- `(?=\susb\b)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a word `usb` ahead of us

Comment: Thanks, perfect, just tried with a shorter version grep -izoP '(?s)ACPI:.*?(?=usb)' , non-greedy was the key!